# Gmail API Firewall settings

Tags: gmail-api

We are calling Gmail API using this code https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet. Everything works fine testing, however when we turn on firewall restrictions it fails.

What is the best way to configure our server to allow connectivity to Gmail API?

Is there a list of IP addresses. How can I make sure it's all up to date.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Gmail firewall settings by referring to this article for a guide:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/9497877?hl=en